# gzclient source code location

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to solve [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16592/simulation-different-when-gzclient-is-open/) issue where my simulation often crashes or is significantly slower when gzclient is not open.
To do that, I am first trying to figure out what changes once I open gzclient. Unfortunately, I am having trouble finding the gzclient source code in the gazebo repository, and would be grateful if someone could provide the link.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16772/gzclient-source-code-location/) by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3232/hamzamerzic/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 40 on 2017-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Most of `gzclient`'s code is under `gazebo/gui`:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/gazebo/gui

This is `gzclient`'s `main`:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/gazebo/gui/main.cc

Note that `gzclient` also uses `gazebo::rendering`, `gazebo::transport`, `gazebo::common`...

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0